# "str.split()" method returns "[0]" instead of splitting the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

I am trying to split a string taken from the cmd using `os.system` but no matter what I split by it always returns `[0]`.

```
import os

username = os.system("whoami /user")
username = (str(username).split(' '))

print(username)
```

For some reason the original output is treated as an integer but that doesn't seem to matter as it is converted to a string.

```
string = "This is a string"
print(string.split(' '))
```

*This works as intended though!*

Comment: If you print out `str(username)`, what do you get? That might help you finding out where the issue lies.

Comment: You're getting the return code of the command (0),not the stdout of the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system` returns the exit code of the command, not the output. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760215/5923139) for more detail (and code that **does** actually get the output). You don't need to run a command to get the username though, just use `getpass.getuser()`:

```py
import getpass
username = getpass.getuser()
```